# php -ajax function not sending data to controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, controller

Ajax function: I can get id in ajax but not able to send to controller. Controller is calling but im not getting data in controller.

```
function select_report()
     {
      var re_id =  $('#report_id').val();
          // ajax adding data to database
          alert(re_id);
         $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('Homepage/category/');?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'re_id':re_id},
           success: function(data)
           {
              window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('Homepage/category/'); ?>";
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
           {
              alert('Error');
           }
       });
     }
```

Controller Function:

```
public function category()
    {
        $this->load->model('main_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $re_id=$this->input->post('re_id');
        print_r($re_id);
        print_r("Welcome");
        exit();
        $data['report']=$this->main_model->select_report($re_id);
        //Code to load header&footer
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('category.php',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Comment: In javascript, use data : {re_id: re_id} instead of data : {'re_id': re_id}

Comment: Thank You , but that also not working ...

Comment: Your url is wrong.

Comment: why did you use:  url : "<?php echo site_url('Homepage/category/');?>", and not url:"page.php" or url:"/homepage/category/"

Comment: Im calling my controller, my controller is "homepage" and "category" is function . Controller is calling no issue in that , but i cant get id in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check.

```
function select_report()
{
     var re_id =  $('#report_id').val();
     $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Homepage/category/',
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {re_id : re_id},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
         }
   });

}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank You, but when try that it is giving error not found.

Answer (score 0):

We can not load view in ajax request. For that, we have used another method

```
 function select_report()
    {
      var re_id =  $('#report_id').val();
      // ajax adding data to database
      alert(re_id);
       $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo site_url('homepage/category/');?>",
          type: "POST",
          data: {'re_id':re_id},
          dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data)
           {
              console.log(data);
              if(data==true){
                window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('homepage/category_demo/'); ?>"+re_id;
              }else{
                alert('Error');
              }
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
           {
              alert('Error');
           }
      });
    }
```

In controller

```
public function category()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $re_id=$this->input->post('re_id');
        $report=$this->main_model->select_report($re_id);
        if(count($report)>0){
            echo json_encode(true);
        }else{
            echo json_encode(false);
        }       

    }
    public function category_demo($re_id){
        $data['report']=$this->main_model->select_report($re_id);
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('category.php',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your help... but not working... first that dataType="json" not working it gives errror. when i removed dataType="Json" and tried showing that data is empty , that else is executing in success function.

Comment: Remove dataType="Json" and Parse result,
success: function(data)
       {
          console.log(data);
          if(JSON.parse(data)==true){ 
            window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('homepage/category_demo/'); ?>"+re_id;
          }else{
            alert('Error');
          }
       },

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome browser, please check on tab **Network** and check what header data send to server. Is that have the data you want to send to your controller, and check what is the response from that URL. Please check the response **HTTP status** also.

And then check on your server side, make sure the the URL can go to your controller. You can die('Test') in you method code to make sure that request touch to your code.

I think the problem come from your URL.

Comment: I debugged  . I cant see any data in header . Url is working  fine, but data is empty

Comment: And what is the response from server?